# Why does chrooted PHP (FPM) have problems with DNS when a chrooted shell does not?

Tags: php, linux, web-services, networking, nginx

#### What I want to do:

Get Nginx to serve PHP files through FastCGI (FPM) from within a chroot jail created using debootstrap.

#### The problem:

Every function that resolves hostnames to IP addresses fails with `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`. What's so odd about this is that there's no problem resolving hostnames from a chrooted shell.

#### What I did so far:

- I disabled the firewall outside the jail.
- I copied */etc/resolv.conf*, */etc/nsswitch.conf* and some other files ([which I found here](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?3,212362,212373#msg-212373)) into the jail. **(All of which were already there thanks to Debootstrap, but I replaced them anyways!)**
- I added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` to */etc/resolv.conf*. **(I haven't done this before, because the nameservers were properly provided by the DHCP server!)**
- I added `domain localhost`<sup>1</sup> to */etc/resolv.conf* and `127.0.0.1 localhost`<sup>1</sup> to */etc/hosts*.
- I installed a nameserver inside the jail.
- I installed a nameserver outside the jail *(oops)*.
- I mounted */proc* inside the jail.

Needless to say that nothing actually fixed the problem, so please help me.

#### All the steps needed to reproduce this:

1. Install Debian Wheezy from *debian-7.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso* and use the default settings for everything except for *Software selection*, leave only *Standard system* checked there.
2. Realize that not picking a less distant mirror was a mistake.

   `vi /etc/apt/sources.list` and made the file look like this:

   ```
   deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

   deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

   deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
   deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
   ```
3. Make sure everything is up to date prior to installing Debootstrap, Nginx and PHP-FPM.

   `aptitude update && aptitude -y full-upgrade`

   `aptitude -y install debootstrap nginx php5-fpm`
4. Use Debootstrap to create the chroot jail for the website.

   `debootstrap wheezy /srv/localhost http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/`<sup>1</sup>
5. Create a directory called *www* with a test file inside the previously created jail and make *www-data* the owner.

   `mkdir /srv/localhost/srv/www`<sup>1</sup>

   `echo "<?php fsockopen('ftp.de.debian.org'); ?>" > /srv/localhost/srv/www/index.php`<sup>1</sup>

   `chown -R 33:33 /srv/localhost/srv/www`<sup>1</sup>
6. Configure and enable the site.

   `vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/localhost`<sup>1</sup> and made the file look like this<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   server {
     listen 127.0.0.1:80;

     server_name localhost;

     root /srv/localhost/srv/www;
     index index.html index.htm index.php;

     location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files     $uri =404;
       fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/localhost.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www/$fastcgi_script_name;
       include       fastcgi_params;
     }

     location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
     }

     location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico)$ {
       access_log off;
     }

     location = /favicon.ico {
       log_not_found off;
     }

     location ~ /\. {
       deny          all;
       access_log    off;
       log_not_found off;
     }
   }
   ```

   `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/localhost /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`<sup>1</sup>
7. Make slight adjustments to the FastCGI parameters provided by Nginx.

   `vi /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` and made the file look like this:

   ```
   fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
   fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
   fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
   fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
   fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
   fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
   fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
   fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

   fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
   fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

   fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
   fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
   fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
   fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
   fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

   # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
   fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
   ```
8. Create a PHP-FPM pool(?) for the site.

   `vi /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/localhost.conf`<sup>1</sup> and made the file look like this<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   [localhost]

   user  = www-data
   group = www-data

   listen                 = /var/run/localhost.sock
   listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

   pm                      = ondemand
   pm.max_children         = 5
   pm.process_idle_timeout = 300s
   pm.max_requests         = 500

   ;access.log    = log/$pool.access.log
   ;access.format = "%R - %u %t \"%m %r\" %s"

   chroot = /srv/localhost/srv
   chdir  = /

   ;catch_workers_output = yes

   ;security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5

   php_flag[display_errors]           = on
   php_admin_flag[log_errors]         = on
   php_admin_value[error_log]         = /var/log/php.log
   php_admin_value[memory_limit]      = 32M
   php_admin_value[session.save_path] = /tmp


   env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
   env[PATH]     = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
   env[TMP]      = /tmp
   env[TMPDIR]   = /tmp
   env[TEMP]     = /tmp
   ```
9. Remove Nginx and PHP-FPM configuration examples.

   `rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/wwww.conf`
10. Restart the PHP-FPM and the Nginx service.

    `service php5-fpm restart && service nginx restart`
11. Inspect the output.

    `wget -qO- http://localhost`<sup>1</sup> prints:

    ```
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in <b>/www/index.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to ftp.de.debian.org:80:-1 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in <b>/www/index.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
    ```
12. Chroot into the jail, just to see that there's no problem with resolving hostnames

    `chroot /srv/localhost/`<sup>1</sup>

    `ping -c1 ftp.de.debian.org` prints:

    ```
    PING ftp.de.debian.org (141.76.2.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from ftp.de.debian.org (141.76.2.4): icmp_req=1 ttl=56 time=15.1 ms

    --- ftp.de.debian.org ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.137/15.137/15.137/0.000 ms
    ```

---

<sup>1</sup> All occurrences of my actual domain have been replaced with localhost and those of my actual IP address with 127.0.0.1.

<sup>2</sup> I've exported the Oracle® VirtualBox appliance and uploaded it on [Mega.co.nz](https://mega.co.nz/#!YNsRwLbB!pav8BwhXgb-aJwibrcYeCJI8XRptOMVKg5ADs5_i2c8) (root password is *password*) for everyone who's really, really eager to help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why that happens, but you could probably find out by using strace. To install strace you'd do a `apt-get install strace`. Then you get the PID of nginx with `ps ax | grep nginx`. Then for the actual stracing:

```
strace -f -s 1024 -p PIDOFNGINX -o /tmp/trace.out
```

Then you fire up that `wget -qO- http://localhost`, stop nginx (or kill strace), and then look through /tmp/trace.out and where it's throwing the error. Probably there's some library missing in your chroot.
**EDIT:** 
The way you have written what you've done you haven't actually performed the test-ping within the chroot. That shoul be:

```
chroot /srv/localhost /bin/ping -c1 ftp.de.debian.org
```

You can actually strace that ping then, which would then include less stuff form nginx. This would require the ping command to be in the chroot as well (which would be needed anyway to test this), including it's depending libraries etc.

Comment: `strace` using `gethostbyname` only from the test-script @ https://knzl.de/setting-up-a-chroot-for-php/ solved `dns` for me in an Alpine Linux / `nginx chroot`.